# iOS: remove navigationbar's background (image)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

At my main view, that contains a menu, I have an image on the navigationbar. When I select one of the menu items, I want to remove the background image and set text, normally.

When the second view opens, the background image still there. I tried everything, following some answers on StackOverflow, but still getting the same error.

I tried this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(36, 36), NO, 0.0);
    UIImage *blank = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:blank forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
```

Didn't work. Tried this:

```
@implementation ViewController{
    UIImage *_bgNavigationBarImage;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    _bgNavigationBarImage = [self.navigationController.navigationBar backgroundImageForBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-home.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:_bgNavigationBarImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

}
```

Didn't work too. Tried to set nil to background and still doesn't working.

Comment: Have you tried doing the changes in `viewDidAppear` and in `viewDidDisappear`? I have found navigation updates can be tricky for buttons and had to move my code here. Perhaps the same applies to background images.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcKinnel I did it and getting the same error. I tried to add the code to remove navigationbar background (second) to viewDidLoad on the second view, and the image still there :(

Comment: And just to check, you removed you appearance code as that would be putting it back.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Could you explain to me?

Comment: You showed some code where you did this: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:...` Just wanted to check you are not setting the image anywhere in your code now.

Comment: Removed the code at viewdidappear and the background image disappeared. So, it's the only code that it's putting the image...

Comment: In your first approach use this code `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:blankImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`

Comment: Ok, added the code: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-home.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; in viewDidAppear and set the blank image in viewDidDisappear. Not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Done!

Used the first method, but changing this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:blank forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

for this:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:blank forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```